# auto-filtering all activerecord queries in rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, filter

on our Rails 3 website we need to filter information dependant on which product customer has access to.

we could do it by adding

```
["product_id in (?)",[allowed_products_array]]
```

in each query executed anywhere in the app for each class which has product_id, but that would be a lot of changes and thus a lot of code to support, so i was thinking about automating this process somehow

what could be the best solution for such auto-filter?

i was thinking about adding global ActiveRecord query override for all classes connected to product but i am not sure how to accomplish that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use default_scope for this

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

in your case s.th. like

```
default_scope where("product_id in (?)",[allowed_products_array])
```

you can extract it into module
and include into every model you'd like to have this functionality.